# Linux Mint shortcut key fails to switch back to previous keyboard layout

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, cinnamon

In Linux Mint with Cinnamon. two keyboard layouts are used; en-CA (useful for accents in french) and en-US.

I set up the shortcut to switch layouts to `super`+`space`. I can switch from en-US to en-CA, but that shortcut will not switch from en-CA to en-US.

Why? Where shall I look to enable this?

EDIT:

Thanks @K7AAY, I am using Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon 3.8.9.

Comment: May I ask which version of Mint you use, and has it always been so or did the shortcut work originally, then fail? Please click [edit] and respond in the question so all may see it.

Comment: I added the version I am using. Sorry it is a late answer